# CopyOnWriteArrayList concurrent access problem on removing

Tags: java, multithreading, copyonwritearraylist

I am struggling to find how to remove an Element of a **CopyOnWriteAccess** without getting a thread exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3649" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.elementAt(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:479)
    at com.mycompany.playmatehunter.Downloader.init(Downloader.java:28)
    at com.mycompany.playmatehunter.Downloader.run(Downloader.java:19)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have the following **Downloader** class

```
public class Downloader extends Thread{
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> url_list;
    private String chemin;

    public Downloader( CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> l, String chemin)
    {
        this.url_list = l;
        this.chemin = chemin;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        init();   
    }

    public synchronized void init() // the list is already synchronized
    {
        if (!url_list.isEmpty())
        {
            int alea = (int)(Math.random()*url_list.size());
            System.out.println(this.getName()+"removes the link nbr "+url_list.get(alea));
            url_list.remove(alea);
        }

    }


}
```

And inside the **main** :

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> index = new CopyOnWriteArrayList( FileToList("/index/index.txt") );

        while( index.size() != 0)
        {
            List<Thread> tg = new ArrayList<Thread>();            
            for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
            {
                Thread t=new Thread(new Downloader(index, ""));
                t.start();
                tg.add(t);
            }

            for(Thread t: tg) 
                t.join();
        }
```

Do you know how to get rid of ThreadException? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your access to the list is not synchronized. You have multiple threads, and even though the `init()` method is synchronized, the synchronization is on the thread instance, not on a common object, so it is useless. If you need to ensure mutual exclusion among threads, you have to synchronize on a common object:

```
 public void init() // No synchronization here
    {
       synchronized(url_list) { // synchronize on a common object
        if (!url_list.isEmpty())
        {
            int alea = (int)(Math.random()*url_list.size());
            System.out.println(this.getName()+"removes the link nbr "+url_list.get(alea));
            url_list.remove(alea);
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you but there is something I don't understand. The CopyOnWriteAccess should be a synchronized object like a synchronized list. Isn't it?

Comment: It is, but you are checking its length and then working on it. Nothing prevents changing the list after you check the length but before you do things with it. You have to synchronize the critical section. The list being synchronized only helps to prevent multiple thread access during an update operation. It won't prevent mutual exclusion when you call it multiple times.